# Set Text on a Circle - Intel XDK

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, intel-xdk

**Please note**: I made a few posts regarding this question a while back, but they were poorly phrased, and I have since deleted the old posts and done a bit more work and research.

So I'm trying to create an app with `Intel XDK` who's sole function is to take text input by the user and display it in a circle. I found the `JS` plugin, `Lettering.js`, which essentially does everything for you. I've been in contact with the creator of Lettering and he's given me quite a bit of help, however he doesn't know how to use Intel XDK which is why I'm turning to Stackoverflow again.

Attached to this post is a collage of my Intel XDK setup (can't have more than 2 links yet). As pictured, I have a separate `CSS` file for transforming the text (image 5), and I have the `Lettering.js` file open in the editor (and the file is in my project folder)(see picture 2). In the `HTML` file header (see picture 3), I reference my `CSS` file, `jQuery`, and the Lettering file. Within the body of the `HTML` file, (see picture 4) I have the code for the textbox and button, as well as the script that is supposed to run the Lettering function and display the text.

The creator of Lettering was kind enough to assist me with a `codepen` [findable here](http://codepen.io/davatron5000/pen/KzxxMg). It works just fine on codepen but it doesn't work in `Intel XDK`. Is there anyone who can assist me? Thank you.

Also please note I'm brand new to learning `JS` and `CSS` so my issue is likely just a beginners mistake. Thanks for your time.

[Link to collage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtPcV.jpg)

Comment: Open the Intel XDK emulator debugging window and click on "console". Do you see some errors?

Comment: It says "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" and then it gives a file path to style.css

Comment: Well, you got your mistake. Try to locate the css file to the correct path.

Comment: I put the css file in its proper folder and set the correct path. Now its telling me "undefined is not a function" as seen in this imgur post http://imgur.com/GkuIjQe

Comment: Check the line 74 in your index. You can also zip your project and upload it.